# Xamarin studio not updating ios entitlements plist option

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have App ID and Provision Profile properly set. But Entitlements.plist file not able to find App ID. When I click on option in entitlements.plist file to enable, Below error displays.

Error is : "An App ID with identifier 'xxxx' is not available. Please enter different string."

I have tried with many different different identifier for iCloud and Data Protection option. but same error always.

Please help me since because of this I am not able to proceed with any entitlement in the Project.

I have latest Xamarin studio and all other component version till today.
Xamarin studio : 6.3 (build 863)

I have installed fastlane and Added Apple accounts to xamarin studio preference.

I have asked question in xamarin forum too. Link : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/269581

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, as I can see the only way to resolve it is change your bundle id string in info plist and recreate provision profiles.